# Escape special character in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I am getting image URL dynamically using PHP. I want to set that image into a `div` background.

All is good but the image URL (it's a blob) when I insert into css it changes `&` into `&amp;` that resulting `404`.

Please have a look in commented code for output.

Can anyone help me keep the URL as it is?

```
<?php
$content = @$this->content[ 'q_view' ][ 'content' ];
preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $content, $matches );    
if ( ! empty( $matches[ 0 ] ) ) {
    $this->_q_header_image = $matches[ 1 ][ 0 ];
} else {
    $this->_q_header_image = $this->rooturl . '/images/q-header-default.jpg';
}    
var_dump($this->_q_header_image) // http://localhost/lion/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=17313457200794318190    
echo '<style>.qa-q-feature-image { background-image: url("' . $this->_q_header_image . '")}</style>';

// http://localhost/lion/?qa=blob&amp;qa_blobid=17313457200794318190
```

Comment: What is wrong with the question so got negative vote?

Comment: Is `<style>`/ [all of it] encoded too? Or just the link?

Comment: `<style>` is outputting as it is. No issue with that. It is just `&`

Comment: First, don't silence code with `@`, that's just bad. Second, it's likely that the AMP is already encoded in the `$content`, and you need to check there.

Comment: Did you try `html_entity_decode($this->_q_header_image)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you saved me.. :) actually, my bad. I came up with this function but I misunderstood by it's name. I thought it does revers than I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: np, though it opens you to XSS, your want to check its a url before.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas thanks a lot for your input. It will help me to learn new things. Appreciate...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decode it before assigning it to `$this->_q_header_image` . Use the below code :-

```
<?php
$content = @$this->content[ 'q_view' ][ 'content' ];
preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $content, $matches );    
if ( ! empty( $matches[ 0 ] ) ) {
    $this->_q_header_image = html_entity_decode($matches[ 1 ][ 0 ]);
} else {
    $this->_q_header_image = $this->rooturl . '/images/q-header-default.jpg';
}    
var_dump($this->_q_header_image) // http://localhost/lion/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=17313457200794318190    
echo '<style>.qa-q-feature-image { background-image: url("' . $this->_q_header_image . '")}</style>';
```

I hope this helps